# I don't know what version is running

Tags: versions

How do I find the version of Ubuntu that is currently running on my system?
I just got this new computer with ubuntu pre-installed and I don't know anything about it.

Comment: While computer is booting,( While you are entering Password) version is displayed in one corner of the screen. (As 13.04 or 13.10 ...)

Answer (score 3):

- Click on the top right corner of your desktop(`an icon that seems like sun or poweroff button`).
- select `About This computer`,it will show you the version of ubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following in a terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```

This will display something like:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```